# How may times should I colour a colour palette to have distinct colours?

Tags: optimization, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Suppose that we have a colour palette, i.e., an array of *n* elements, which needs to be coloured by distinct numbers. We are only allowed to use 0 or 1 to colour every elements in each colouring step. In every step, we try to use almost uniformly distributed colours. For example, for *n* = 4, in the first step we may add the 1st slice of colour  {0, 1, 0, 1}, in the second step we may add the second slice of colour {0, 0, 1, 1}, and voilà done! now every elements has a distinct colour, {00, 10, 01, 11}.

How may times should we colour a palette of *n* elements to have distinct colours?

Note: I am looking for complete answers.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly with $k$ steps, each of which makes only a $2$-way distinction, you can distinguish at most $2^k$ elements. Suppose that $2^k<n\le 2^k+1$. Number the $n$ elements $0$ through $n-1$, and write the $n$ numbers in binary as $(k+1)$-bit numbers (with leading zeros as needed). On pass $i$ add a slice to each element whose $i$-th bit is $1$; this will result in distinct colors for each of the $n$ elements. Thus, the number of passes needed is $\lceil\log_2n\rceil$.

Comment: @Jolfaei: That $\lceil\lg n\rceil$ is provably the smallest number of binary passes that can distinguish $n$ colors, so an $\lceil\lg n\rceil$ algorithm is at least as fast as any $O(\lceil\lg n\rceil)$ algorithm.

Comment: If we name the constant coefficient as *C*, is there a proof to show that in my method 1< *C*.

Comment: @Jolfaei: You haven’t specified a method in enough detail for me to be sure. It’s possible that what you have in mind has $C=1$, but it’s certain that $C\not<1$, because $m$ steps can produce at most $2^m$ different colors, and if $m<\lceil\lg n\rceil$, then $2^m<n$. (I apologize, but I need to go run some errands now; I will check back tomorrow, however.)